# How to check transaction in MPL Paypal sandbox?

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am working on application which required `paypal` integration.

I have successfully integrated `MPL Paypal sdk`.

While Testing  I can see successfully transaction in notification under sandbox section.

[image: See Image below]

But in the transaction bar I didn't get anything.

[image]

I don't understand the reason for this.

Is transaction is visible in paypal sandbox?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per new design of paypal website there is no dependency on [developer website](https://developer.paypal.com/) and  [sandbox website](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/home).

Once you get notification for your transcation  in developer account go to the sandbox website.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/home

You can see each and every transaction there.

Answer (score -1):

Because your transactions is not approved.
Notifycation list show the notifycation between paypal and your website, it just is a method of paypal that help your website receive status of transaction but it is not transaction.